# Converting a substring char to an int from a string value then assigning it to an int variable

Tags: c++, type-conversion

so my program takes input as in "A1, A2, B2, H8", etc. as coordinates. When the user enters for example, 'A1', they are assigned to a string called "spaceInput". But in order for the for loop (outside the chunk of the code below) to iterate and find the matching number, '1', it must be turned into an int then assigned to 'numberInput'.

I used 'stoi()' but the problem is that it needs to be safe guarded or else it crashes, for example, like when someone enters something like 'AA'. The code works fine but is there a better way to convert a char from a string into an int?

```
void TakeInput() {

    string spaceInput;
    int numberInput;
    char letterInput;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter your space input: " << endl;
        cin >> spaceInput;
        cout << spaceInput << endl;
        cin.get();
        letterInput = toupper(spaceInput[0]);// Converts letter input to uppercase

        try { 
            int numberInput = stoi(spaceInput.substr(1)); 
               if (spaceInput.size() == 2 && numberInput < ROWS && numberInput > 0) {
                SearchSpace(spaceInput, letterInput, numberInput);
                cout << "Your input was: " << letterInput << numberInput << endl;
               }

               else {

                cout<< "Invalid input: " << endl;

            }
        }   catch (exception const &e) {
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First check with [std::isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)

Comment: `size_t pos = spaceInput.find_first_of("0123456789"); if (pos != std::string::npos) numberInput = spaceInput.at(pos) - '0';`. (for single-digit substrings, otherwise use your `numberInput = stoi(spaceInput.substr(pos));` with the `try/catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think regex would be the most safe and straight forward solution. I don't think this is overkill since you create the regex once, but match it multiple times.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(void)
{
    std::string input;
    std::regex regex("[A-Z|a-z][0-9]");

    while (true) {
        std::cin >> input;

        if (std::regex_match(input, regex)) {
              char letter = input[0];
              int number = atoi(&input[1]);

             std::cout << "Input letter: " << input[0] << std::endl;
              std::cout << "Input number: " << number << std::endl;;
        } else {
              std::cout << "Formatting error\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, atoi was a bit more helpful in this case. But I read you need to call  .c_str for atoi()?

Comment: Yes you'll probably need to call it like this : `atoi(&input[1].c_str())` since atoi is taking a `char *` in parameter